# Convert 3-way switch to single pole smart switch

Tags: electrical

So we basically don't need a 3-way switch, so I can get rid of one of them, and install a smart single-pole switch on the other one. How would that work?

Also, I just opened the switch, and apparently there are only 2 black and 1 red wires there, so no white wire.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both switch boxes? Also, where are the switches located with respect to the room they're in? (It may be the case that Code *requires* a 3-way switching setup in this application)

Comment: Does your local Code require a 3-way switch here?  This is always the case on stairways and sometimes the case on rooms with two entrances.